# Purpose of on_new_message in RASA

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

What is the function of on_new_message and how is it callable in Rasa?

I was trying to create an output channel and found on_new_message function. I am able to create the channel but still wondering what is it doing in Background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an `OutputChannel` there is no `on_new_message` function.
The `on_new_message` function is a callback which gets passed to your `InputChannel`. You use it to pass the received message to Rasa Core after you have parsed it. A typical workflow might be:

1. Start Rasa Core which sets your custom `InputChannel` up.
2. A user writes a message within an app (e.g. Slack, Telegram)
3. The app (e.g. Slack, Telegram) forwards this message by calling the endpoint of your `InputChannel`
4. You parse the message
5. You pass the content of the message to Rasa Core by calling `on_new_message`
6. You either return the bots answer directly (see `RestInput` as an example) or you use a separate `OutputChannel` for that (see class `SlackBot` for an example)

The documentation of Rasa Core has also a section on how to create custom channels: [Creating a new Channel](https://rasa.com/docs/core/connectors/#creating-a-new-channel)

Comment: And on_new_message is calling the function agent.handle_message

Comment: @SUBHOJEET Please mark your question as solved, if this answer helped  you.